# About pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have questions about **pthread_cond_signal** and **pthread_cond_wait**. For example, in the code below, According to my understanding, when **inc_count** calls **pthread_cond_signal**, *count += 125* in **watch_count** can be executed only after **count_mutex** is unlocked in **inc_count**.

The **count_mutex** was unlocked in **watch_count** when **pthread_cond_wait** executed and only gets locked after **pthread_mutex_unlock** in **inc_count** is executed. Am I right?

```
void *inc_count(void *t) 
{
    int i;
    long my_id = (long)t;

    for (i = 0; i < TCOUNT; i++) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
        count++;

        if (count == COUNT_LIMIT) 
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *watch_count(void *t) 
{
    long my_id = (long)t;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    while (count < COUNT_LIMIT)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
        count += 125;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread_cond_wait()` unlocks the mutex on entry and locks it again on exit. If another thread acquires the lock during that time, `pthread_cond_wait()` cannot return until that other thread has released the lock.

So, if `watch_count()` is blocked in `pthread_cond_wait()`, and `inc_count()` runs and calls `pthread_cond_signal()`, then `watch_count()` will not return from `pthread_cond_wait()` until `inc_count()` has called `pthread_mutex_unlock()`.

However, `pthread_cond_wait()` can wake even if not signalled. This is called a spurious wake-up. `watch_count()` can therefore execute `count+=125` many times, even if `inc_count()` never runs, or never calls `pthread_cond_signal()`.

Answer (score 0):

> count += 125 in watch_count can be executed only after count_mutex is unlocked in inc_count

Yes.

> The count_mutex was unlocked in watch_count when pthread_cond_wait executed and only gets locked after pthread_mutex_unlock in inc_count is executed.

Yes, in the sense that when `pthread_cond_wait` returns `watch_count` holds the mutex, and thus it will only return after `inc_count` has unlocked the mutex. (Provided `COUNT` starts out below `COUNT_LIMIT` when the `while` is first reached..)

BTW: This code hurts my head a little. I really wouldn't recommend modifying `count` in `watch_count` as the control flow could get hard to figure out if you ever have more than one thread running that function and you start to use `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

Comment: I copied this code from a POSIX Threads tutorial, so its just for learning purposes.