# Does pthread_cond_wait and pthread_mutex_unlock conflict?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am implementing manual reset event using pthread in Linux which is similar to WaitForSingleEvent in Windows. I found this post

[pthread-like windows manual-reset event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178114/pthread-like-windows-manual-reset-event)

and follow it, however there a thing that confuse me:

```
void mrevent_wait(struct mrevent *ev) {
     pthread_mutex_lock(&ev->mutex);
     while (!ev->triggered)
         pthread_cond_wait(&ev->cond, &ev->mutex);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&ev->mutex);
}
```

- pthread_cond_wait: 
  Atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable cond;
- pthread_mutex_unlock:
  Attempts to unlock the specified mutex. If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL, error detection is not provided. If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that is **has not locked** or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.

What I am scare is when pthread_cond_wait release the mutex, **then pthread_mutex_unlock may come undefined behavior** (this kind of thing would drive me crazy, how come they not handle it :-D )

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) says:

> Upon successful return, the mutex has
>   been locked and is owned by the
>   calling thread.

Which means that when returning, `pthread_cond_wait` **atomically** locks the associated mutex.

The workflow is like this:

- You lock a mutex

  - `pthread_cond_wait` atomically blocks and unlocks the mutex (so other threads might get here)
  - When a condition arrives, `pthread_cond_wait` atomically returns and locks the mutex
- You unlock the mutex

> I don't think pthread_cond_wait blocks
>   and unlocks

That's because you didn't read the link I provided.

> These functions **atomically release
>   mutex and cause the calling thread to
>   block** on the condition variable cond;

Comment: In conclusion it's valid (and required) to unlock the mutex after `pthread_cond_wait`.

Comment: I don't think pthread_cond_wait blocks and unlocks. But if it first unlock the mutex and then try to lock back the mutex, I think it may lead to a deadlock here. And BTW, anyone knows why we must put pthread_cond_wait into a while loop? Can I just using an if statement? Thank you!

Comment: @longbkit See my edited answer. Your second question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505567/about-pthread-cond-signal-and-pthread-cond-wait/6507488#6507488