# pthread_cond_wait isn't doing what I'm expecting

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix

I am trying to use pthread_cond_wait in the way I think it should be used. I use it in a method, that is waiting for something to change, and when it does it will call another method to get the data. it looks like below:

```
void waitForSomething(const std::string& _str) {

    //lock my mutex here

     while (!ifStringInSomeCollection(_str)) {
             std::cout << "waiting.." << std::endl;
             pthread_cond_wait(&_condMutex, &_myMutex);
     }
     //unlock my mutex here

     //this method also acquires my mutex lock
     std::cout << getData(_str) << std::endl;
}
```

Now in my other method that will break the condition and broadcast/signal the waiting condition, I first unlock the mutex before broadcasting/signalling - so that should not be an issue.

But even without that, what currently happens is, it constantly checks for condition in the while loop instead of pthread_cond_wait - actually waiting. I've been stuck with this for a while, any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

==================

Following discussion, I wrote the following to test, to get the condition to wait in a test situation. I still get repeated "locked" message. I must be doing something wrong? http://ideone.com/eVuKEC

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
bool something;

void test() {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while(!something) {
      std::cout <<"locked" << std::endl;
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main(){
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
   pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);  
   something=false;  
   test();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check the return value - it could be that it returns an error and that's why you're looping.

Comment: I assume that `_condMutex` is a `pthread_cond_t` (the name of the variriable is a bit misleading, since a condvar isn't a mutex) and that it's been initialized properly?

Comment: yes you're right it is a pthread_cond_t variable. pmod, i just printed the return value of pthread_cond_wait - it is 0, and it is also being printed repeatedly as you'd expect.

Comment: also i initialise the variable in the constructor like this : pthread_cond_init(&_condMutex, NULL);

Comment: @OriginalCliche maybe you have "spurious wakeup" problem: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505567/about-pthread-cond-signal-and-pthread-cond-wait

Comment: yes it most probably is a "spurious wakeup", i had a look on that page earlier, for the sake of testing, at present i am not signalling anything, i am just expecting it to wait, not sure what i need to do to fix it..

Comment: @OriginalCliche if no signalling threads and you still see the same, this is not "spurious wakeup", because it's just about waking up more than one thread from one signal

Comment: @OriginalCliche could it be that you are corrupting memory somewhere, e.g. in ifStringInSomeCollection()...

Comment: @pmod i can't be corrupting memory as ifStringInSomeCollection() simply searches a map which will return a bool either true or false.

Comment: @OriginalCliche You need to lock the mutex/unlock around (before/after) the wait.

Comment: @sree i am doing that, check the comments.

Comment: @OriginalCliche tried your code and it does NOT repeatedly print "locked" for me.  works as expected (prints "locked" once). some other issue?

Comment: Likewise with sree's results here. Apart from a poorly named variable (`mutex` is a class name in C++11) it works as expected. I think you may have other issues.

Comment: hanks Everyone for your input - please excuse the poor variable name - that is not how it is in production code, had quickly change names etc to not publish prop code, and in the haste and frustration.. =] It did indeed was a simple case of passing -pthread into my makefile. Thanks @fizzer for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with the -pthread option to g++

Comment: ahhhhh! this must be it. i was messing around on ideone and it doesn't pass that option. i will write it up at work tomorrow in linux, and build it there, and report back. thanks